# How to export .wsp solution files from SharePoint 2007 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, solution-package, export, download

I want to download/export all .wsp solution files from SharePoint 2007 farm in order to deploy them again on new environment. How can i export or download .wsp files? I don't want to extract .wsp files. I just want the copies of all .wsp files. How its possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generic idea

1. Using `stsadm -o enumsolutions` get all installed solutions on the farm
2. Then for each solution you need to download it using following technique

   - [Enable Powershell] (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968930)

   `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Cult ure=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")`

   `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")`

After this you can extract the files from the configuration database:

```
$farm = [microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm]::Local

$wsp = $farm.Solutions.Item("solutionname.wsp").SolutionFile

$wsp.SaveAs("c:\solutionname.wsp")
```

http://spsolution.wordpress.com/2012/11/07/extract-wsp-file-from-configuration-database/

Answer (score 4):

If you get an error adding SharePoint DLL which states

```
Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sharepoint, Version=12.0.0.0
```

you can try using this script instead

```
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
```

and you can continue exporting the WSP from your 2007 environment

```
$farm = [microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm]::Local
$wsp = $farm.Solutions.Item("documentmanagement.actions.wsp").SolutionFile
$wsp.SaveAs("c:\temp\documentmanagement.actions.wsp")
```

Reference: [Running PowerShell on MOSS 2007](http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/01/22/running-powershell-on-moss-2007.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this post is quite old, however I just ran into this issue myself during a 2007 migration project. In my case, there were quite a few solutions and downloading each one manually wasn't exactly ideal for me. I created a folder "solutions" on the C: drive and modified the above script to download all solutions into that folder.

```
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$farm = [microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm]::Local
$solutions = $farm.Solutions
ForEach ($solution in $solutions) {
    $wsp = $farm.Solutions.Item($solution.Name).SolutionFile
    $file = "C:\solutions\" + $solution.Name
    $wsp.SaveAs($file)
}
```

Hope this helps someone out there.