# How to export wsp file from sharepoint 2007 and import it to sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, wspbuilder, sharepoint-farm

How to export a 
wsp file from sharepoint 2007 and import it to sharepoint 2010. Also what all are things that we should keep in mind before & after the process

Answer (score 1):

For extracting you can use Solution Extractor Tool from below link

http://blogs.technet.com/b/patrick_heyde/archive/2009/08/28/how-to-extract-wsp-files-from-sharepoint.aspx

Once you have extracted the wsp. You can use PowerShell for installing it into your SharePoint 2010 environment.

```
Add-SPSolution c:\path\wspname.wsp

Install-SPSolution –Identity wspname.wsp –WebApplication http://sp2010url -GACDeployment
```

Ideal way is to upgrade your visual studio solution to 2010.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2010/09/09/updating-a-sharepoint-2007-wsp-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Theres a similar question & answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121555/how-to-export-wsp-solution-files-from-sharepoint-2007-farm) regarding exporting wsp from SP 2007.

You could use Powershell to install in SP 2010. Refer this [post](http://onceinawhilescribble.blogspot.com/2014/02/basic-powershell-for-sharepoint-and.html)

Eg:
To add to farm

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "C:\FolderName\Solution.wsp"
```

Deploy to Site Collection

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity "Solution.wsp" -WebApplication "http://WebSiteUrl" -CASPolicies -GACDeployment -Local -Force
```

The parameteres are explained in the post.
Note: CasPolicies is depricated in SP2013 in case you need to deploy in SP2013 later on.